# Default values for unknown elements in mORMot / Synopse JSON

Tags: json, delphi, mormot

I really love the way mORMot / Synopse has implemented the handling of JSON, especially the way you can use the JSON elements in your code (like `MyString := myjson.name`). This is very intuitive and useful in wrapping objects which only have one Variant (JSON) with state which we access through getters/setters, like below:

```
  TMyObject = class
  private
    FState: Variant;

    function GetName: String;
  public
    constructor Create(AJson: Variant);

    property Name: String read GetName;
  end;

  function TMyObject.GetName: String;
  begin
    Result := FState.name;
  end;
```

It is really powerful, but I would like to get the 'default' variant value if an element is not found in the corresponding JSON document (so, above example should return an empty string if 'name' is not present).

I don't want to use `NullStrictConvert`, because that is not thread safe and influences the rest of our program. Of course I could check `VarIsNull(FState.name)`, but then I have to do this for each element and I prefer not to have this extra boilerplate.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

When you unserialize some JSON into an object, the missing fields are left untouched IIRC.

So you can just set the fields to their default values before unserializing the JSON.

One way of doing it is to inherit from `TSynPersistent` and override the `Create` constructor and set default value(s).

Edit: You may use a `TDocVariantData` instead of `variant`, and call `GetAsRawUTF8()` and such methods which return `false` if the property is not existing.

Comment: I suppose this is true if we would use JSONToObject, but we are not. Is there any other possibility in that case?

Comment: This saved my bacon today :-)